# Tensorflow, model.predict for a input_arry with 4 columns and 3 lines

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I watched a tutorial on youtube and tried to adapt the source text to my needs. Link to the video is allowed?

In the tutorial there is an input array with one row and 3 columns filled with numbers (1,2,3). There is also an output tensor of the same size, also filled with three numbers (1,2,6). The relationship between the numbers is learned. In the tutorial the AI ​​recognizes that: output = input^2 and make a prediction for example 4 --> 8.

I wanted to try making a prediction using arrays.

I have several measured values:
Water: 10, 11, 15, 2
Temperature: 2, 5, 17, 4
Speed:3, 7, 6, 1

this includes the following values (calculated values (from the measured values)):
A = 1, 5, 7, 4
B = 2, 4, 1, 5

I would like to predict the measurement values ​​for the case A = 6 AND B = 3

I have tried a lot of things.
in my opinion i make a mistake with the first neuron layer: layer.dense (units and shape) and the command model.predict (array dimension)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.utils import np_utils

#the model from the tutorial
#model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

#my model
model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Dense(units=3, input_shape=[2]),  # units=???=colums from input_array? input_shape=?  
    keras.layers.Dense(units=128),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

#model.compile from the tutorial
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

#xs=[1, 2, 3] #input_array from tutorial
#ys=[2, 4, 6] #output_array from tutorial

#my output array
output_array = (  [10, 11, 15, 2],      #Water,   array shape = (3,4)   ndim = Dimension = 2
                 [2, 5, 17, 4],        #Temperature
                 [3, 7, 6, 1]          #Speed 
               )

#my input array
input_array = (
                 [1, 5, 7, 4],         #A
                 [2, 4, 1, 5],         #B
                 )

#model.fit from the tutorial - I use the same one
model.fit(output_array, input_array, epochs=500)


print(model.predict([6],[3]))
```

I would be very happy about help and some source text.

thx, Rocco

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your input array should be example * variables.

[[1, 2], [5, 4], [7, 1], [4, 5]]

Same for your output array shape. You need to make the necessary shape adjustments.

Your last layer should have units=num_output_variables. So 3 in your case.